# How can I set h,j,k,l to be movement keys in VIM for Windows?

Tags: windows, vim

I installed VIM for Windows due to issues with my Samba setup (I'm unable to edit a file on my linux machine and use it on my windows machine without copying it explicitly).  Imagine my surprise when I found that h,j,k,l aren't movement keys in VIM.  I'm forced to use the arrow keys!

How can I fix this so that the keys work as expected?

Comment: Is it possible that you started the "Easy" version of Vim?  That would make the arrow keys your method of moving around.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have all the [right components for Windows vim installed](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc). The easiest way to do this is use the self-extracting installer, currently [gvim72.exe](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim72.exe).

I just installed, as a test, gvim72.exe on a Windows XP system and the hjkl movement keys work fine. Try uninstalling whatever you have and reinstalling with the installer.

Your file editing issue with samba should be posted as well, though the answer is likely to make sure the user you are accessing the share is on the 'write list' in the smb.conf.